# "Generate Step Defintions" context menu missing in Specflow V1.9

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, specflow

"Generate Step Defintions" context menu missing in Specflow V1.9.When i select the particular scenario, the one which i have to generate the step definitions, i am unable to get the option "Generate Step Defintions".This hinders my specflow process.Could any one help out on how to go about this process.

Comment: have you installed both the [Visual studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c74211e7-cb6e-4dfa-855d-df0ad4a37dd6) AND the nuget package?

Comment: @Sam Holder:I have installed  Visual studio extension but have not installed nuget package, will install the same and check it out!

Comment: @Sam Holder: Even after installing the nuget package i am facing the same issue.

Comment: are your feature files syntax highlighted (ie are the keywords coloured ect)?

Comment: @Sam Holder:yes syntax is highlighted!

Comment: All I can suggest then is to uninstall and reinstall both the extension and the nuget package. Which version of VS?

Comment: I'd see if it works in VS2012+ as I have a feeling it might be related to you using such an old version

Comment: @Sam Holder:i unistalled the same and re-installed it and i got the "Generate step definitions" context but when i created a new application and a specflow along with it , the "Generate Step Definitions" does not appear and i get an error as:The type or namespace name 'TechTalk' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That sounds like you don't have the nuget package installed

Comment: @Sam Holder:Have installed the  Nuget Package manager